# "Adding motion" usage in sentence/slogan

Tags: grammar, slogan

english is not my tongue language and I am working on a new viral content website, where I am trying to come up with slogan.
Would be correct to say: **"Adding motion to your daily boredom"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that the "adding to" phrasing doesn't make much sense.

How about "Moving you through your daily boredom" instead? It retains the "motion" concept but sounds more natural to me.

You could explore synonyms to both "moving" as well. "Propelling" or "Driving" are also strong active verbs that share the transportation theme.

Answer (score 0):

It would be grammatically correct, but doesn't really make sense. Why would making my boredom move be a good thing.

You might want to consider "Adding excitement" instead

Comment: Adding excitement to boredom doesn't work either.

Comment: My thought behind this is that "Motion" (moving forward, doing something) is opposite to boredom (doing nothing and being bored ). Furthermore, this will be a website featuring "buzzfeed" style stories about transport vehicles,bikes, skateboards and etc. But if it doesn't make sense, I will keep working on it... Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

As a born to English user, may I suggest a different approach ?  Consider dropping the use of 'boredom'.  No one likes to actually *admit * they are bored.

Instead emphasize the positive with some thing like:
"Making travel more exciting than the destination..."